# Do we need to add automation coverage for customer bugs?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

As currently, we are having coverage for P1 test cases for an end to end scenarios. We are following the test pyramid strategy. But now we are planning to cover the customer bugs. So just want to know whether we need to provide automation coverage for all bugs or not.

Comment: The test pyramid does not specificy which level a bug would be fixed at - it could be any.

Answer (score 3):

Recently been in similar situation and  after analysis found an interesting co- relation of bugs found.

> **The result of the analysis was bugs hide in clusters mostly in few
>   specific  areas only**.

In other words bugs are not scattered all across the application but mostly exist in clusters in few area only.

So instead of mapping 1 to 1 to each production bug , we added/updated few end to end scenarios in these areas covering most of these issues path + few additional related validations.

This is working very well now as we are finding most of these bugs (if any) in regression test runs only. And automation is being considered very effective by business analysts as well.

Answer (score 1):

### It depends

It depends on your system functionality, your current test case coverage, your current test type allocation (based on the testing pyramid and the Agile Testing
Quadrants

[image]

[image]

Your basic choice is always:  Update an existing unit/integrated/UI tests or create a new unit/integrated/UI test.  Yo should do that in the following order which prioritizes updates existing tests over creating new ones and also prioritizes unit over integration and both over UI testing - the slowest and least reliable form.  The order means that if you can do a low level tests instead of a high level one, you should do that

- Review the existing Unit cases and see if a specific example is missing

else

- Add a brand new Unit test case

else

- Review the existing Integration tests and see if a specific example is missing

else

- Add a brand new integration test

else

- Review the existing UI tests and see if a specific example is missing

else

- Add a brand new UI case

else

- Add a new manual test case

else

- Add new items to the exploratory testing charter

Comment: downvoter - you have a different approach? or you think this is actually wrong? I am most curious.

Comment: I am very confused with my downvoters. I guess people are not used to design test automation from logical side. Other explanation I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

Reported defects are not covered specifications, it is behaviour not anticipated. I would always add an automated test for each found defect, as it is probably is the brittle part of the application. It also documents the new expected behaviour.

Now what kind of test you write depends on the defect. Preferably you first write a failing test to reproduce the defect and then fix it. I would try to start reproducing it in a unit-test and slowly go up the pyramid if needed.

Answer (score -3):

1. My first question to you - what is your criteria for regression tests? How do you choose what to automate and what to not? I guess you don't have it, because it should answer your own question. It is not a problem to automate something, it is challenge **to automate the right test cases**. We learn from bugs raised by customers, but only in few cases we really need to automate them.
2. Since we cannot automate everything **typical** criteria for e2e is to automate 
   1) only standard features
   2) high risk
   3) most used
3. If you are living in agile world, I would suggest you to read a book "[Agile testing](https://agiletester.ca)" by Janet Gregory & Lisa Crispin. In their book they have several chapters on **Agile Quadrants** and chapter on **Test Automation Strategy**. They suggest to write e2e tests for epics, integration tests for stories and unit tests for tasks.
4. Another idea would be to take free training on [Test Automation Strategy](http://angiejones.tech/test-automation-strategy/) at [Test Automation University](https://testautomationu.applitools.com).
5. More test automation strategy modules, collected by Lisa Crispin you will find on [JoeColantonio](https://www.joecolantonio.com/modeling-automation-2/) website.

Comment: Hey, downvoter, I am curious and would like to know why you did not like my answer.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I see two reasons why someone would: 1) self promotion without full disclosure in the post is against policy, so that's a big one. 2) the answer doesn't seem to address the question. Those will probably need to be addressed for the community to view it favorably.

Comment: As an addition (also not the downvoter): "Janet & Lisa" is not really helpful if you have no clue who they are and what to look for. Full names, titles and a reference to the actual book(s) is much more helpful.

Comment: Thank you, @RayOei, for comment. It was not helpful to assume that everyone knows who are Janet & Lisa.

Comment: @corsiKa I removed the link. According answering the question - in testing you never do automation for bugs, but for features. I described both ways how to do it.

Comment: @kriscorbus For there record, self promotion is perfectly fine as long as it's properly attributed. :-) Also, I have to disagree that we never do automation for bugs. I often write automated tests to capture bugs because if we made that mistake once, we will likely make it again, and it clearly wasn't captured the first time. I'm tempted to ask a new question on that just to elicit further elaboration, but fear it may be too similar to this particular one to stand up to the "not a dupe" test.

Comment: @corsiKa "I often write automated tests to capture bugs because if we made that mistake once, we will likely make it again" Sorry, but this is not suggested approach for e2e tests. Not to make this conversation too intense, I will suggest you something completely different. Keynote from Kate Gregory. She talks about emotions in the code, in her talk she analyses code and gives some suggestions for unit testing. I hope you will like it: https://youtu.be/SzoquBerhUc